# how to make for loop in treeview winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, nodes

So I have problem with setting my for loop. I have button click event where I am reading Node text and writing to another file some text using appendline. Here is my code:

```
private void  button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var header = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\dir\header.tex");
   var footer = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\dir\footer.tex");
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.AppendLine(header);

   if (treeView1.Nodes[0].Text == ("chaper1")) sb.AppendLine(@"\include {chap1}");
   if (treeView1.Nodes[1].Text == ("chapter2")) sb.AppendLine(@"\include {chap2}");
   if (treeView1.Nodes[2].Text == ("chapter3")) sb.AppendLine(@"\include {chap3}");
   if (treeView1.Nodes[3].Text == ("chapter4")) sb.AppendLine(@"\include {chap4}");

   sb.AppendLine(footer);
   File.WriteAllText(@"C: \dir\final.tex", sb.ToString());
}
```

My program is removing nodes from added nodes. So If i remove one node, for example `treeview1.node[2]`, `my node[3]`, becomes `node[2]`. How to set this for loop? Or maybe there is other options?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you have some dynamic nodes?

Comment: Yes, My button event 2 remove chosen added nodes. Changes are shown on the winform window, and then I want to click button 3, and add nodes appendline text to file, from node that are not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `foreach` loop over your treeview [`Nodes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodes(v=vs.110).aspx) collection, for example:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
{
    sb.AppendLine(node.Text);
}
```

Also if you want to add some other text that `node.Text` you can store the other string in `Tag` property of the node when you create the node and add it to tree, for example, when adding a node:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode("Text") { Tag = "Some Other Text" });
```

And when using:

```
var tag= node.Tag as string;
sb.AppendLine(string.IsNullOrEmplty(text)?node.Text:tag);
```

Comment: Maybe you can show tag example? My adding process looks like: `treeview1.Nodes.add("chapter1") ` and so on.

Comment: Yes, If you think it's helpful, I'll also add a `Tag` example.

Comment: and on this code what you are offering I will write a node.text to a file if I get right?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, you can write a different text than your `node.Text` even you can have an object in your `Tag` property of the node and use it later.

Comment: Thank you very very much. You helped me a lot everything looks working perfectly :)

Comment: Maybe you can show me how to do it with node children? :) Again index problems :/

Comment: Also each node  has a `Nodes` property that you can loop over that property same as above.

Comment: Do you need to find all nodes and child nodes in a flat structure? or you need to have them in a hierarchy?

Comment: Okey, but for example take out nodes[4], so so nodes[5].nodes isn't nodes[5].nodes anymore :) how to set up this foreach loop again?

Comment: I think you don't need to work with node indexes, `foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes){ foreach (TreeNode child in node.Nodes){ /* ... */}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a name with your node,

for example:

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() {Name="1",Text="chaper1" });
treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Name = "2", Text = "chaper2" });
treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Name = "3", Text = "chaper3" });
```

This way you can search by name and not for index

Comment: My nodes have name. But as I said if I remove node, the index is changing. I tried this what you offered, but it is not working because. After adding node, I am doing one more step to remove them. So what is happening when I use this: I add text to file, but I am not removing anything.